# inequality for a symmetric nonnegative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities

Given $A$ symmetric and semidefinite positive, for each $x$
$$ x'Ax \geq \frac{1}{\Vert A\Vert} \Vert Ax \Vert^2 $$

This inequality appears at page 24 of "Introduction to Optimization" from Boris T. Polyak. I haven't been able to prove it.
Any idea?

Thanks,
Giovanni

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is that $|A\| x' A x \ge \|A x\|^2 = x' A^2 x$, i.e. that $\|A\| A \ge A^2$.
This comes from $\|A\| I \ge A$ by multiplying on the left and right by the positive semidefinite square root of $A$.